# Spring: boolean variables in objects get returned

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson

Let's say I have an object:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Foods {

    public Foods() {}

    @Id
    @JsonProperty
    private String id;

    @JsonProperty
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty
    private Double calories;

    @JsonProperty
    private boolean sweet;

    }
```

Now, in my Spring REST API call, I only populate the "name" field for the food and return it.

I get this as the return JSON:

```
  {
    "name": "Strawberry Pies",
    "sweet": false
  }
```

You can see that because the calories is not populated, the JSON doesn't return it. The "sweet" field I guess gets populated because the default value for boolean is false.

I do not however want the JSON string to return the "sweet" boolean of false if it was not populated in the first place. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Simple answer is that `NON_NULL` means, well, "Do not inlude `null` values". If `String`-valued fields are not initialized, they will be `null`s. But `boolean` is primitive type, for which nulls are never used: `false` is not `null`. If you do want it to be excluded, you can make "sweet" to be of type `Boolean` (that is, `java.lang.Boolean`), wrapper that does allow `null`s as well. Or, like another answer suggested, just use `NON_DEFAULT`.

Comment: @StaxMan Does Jackson instantiate the class once (with parameterless constructor) to check the DEFAULT value and compare against the instance you pass for serialization? What is the motivation for this? (As opposed to just default initialization values.)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It does not mean "whatever defaults are for primitives". It literally means "default values for this class when instantiated (with no-args ctor)" -- and to know what that would be, one needs an instance to check what those default values are.

Comment: @StaxMan Nono, what you're saying is what I mean. I'm curious as to why it was done that way. Is that a common scenario (as opposed to not serializing default initialization values, 0, false, null)?

Comment: @StaxMan I'm worried about that unexpected instance creation.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It is indeed common for developers to define Java classes in such a way that fields have values other than `null`s (for object types) and defaults for primitives. If that is not the behavior you want, you may try other choices for inclusion, or custom filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotate your field (or property getter/setter) with

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)
private boolean sweet;
```

The javadoc of `NON_DEFAULT` states

> Value that indicates that only properties that have values that differ
>   from default settings (meaning values they have when Bean is
>   constructed with its no-arguments constructor) are to be included.

With

```
private boolean sweet;
```

that default value would've been `false`. If that's the value that field had for the object you serialized, the JSON would not contain it.

Similarly, if you had

```
private boolean sweet = true;
```

and the field for the corresponding object had a value of `true`, the generated JSON would also not contain it.